# Strapi - How to extend graphql type schema with custom property?

Tags: graphql, strapi

Let's say I have '*firstName*' and '*lastName*' properties on an Author type schema created as Strapi content type.

I am able to query them with graphql, but what if I want to query '*fullName*' property without adding that field on my content type?

As field doesn't exist, now it says: *Cannot query field \"fullName\" on type \"Author\"*.

How can I extend existing type schema with that additional "virtual" field?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do it with the following code in the *schema.graphql* file placed inside the *api/author/config* folder:

```js
module.exports = {
  definition: `type AuthorOverride {
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  fullName: String
}`,
  query: `
    authors: [AuthorOverride]
  `,
  type: {
    Author: false
  },
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      authors: {
        description: 'Return the authors',
        resolver: 'Author.find'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The key was to define schema with additional field while using different type name (AuthorOverride) to avoid duplicate type error.

Also, to set type: { Author: false } so that original type won't be queriable.

Now, inside my resolver function 'Author.find' (placed in my Author.js controller) I can map fullName value.

If someone has a more appropriate solution for extending graphql schema in Strapi, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this post and also found the **appropriate solution**. This [example repo](https://github.com/strapi/foodadvisor/tree/master/api/api/restaurant) demonstrates how to use a service function with custom controller methods and a custom GraphQL schema to get what you want. I just implemented the same in my own project.

Your case would not need a service function. You just need to do 2 things:

1. Define `fullName` property in `/api/authors/config/schema.graphql.js` like below:

```js
module.exports = {
  definition:
    extend type Author {
      fullName: AuthorFullName
    }

    type AuthorFullName {
      firstName: String
      lastName: String
    }
  `,
};
```

2. Next, you need to override the `find` and `findOne` controller methods for `Author` like below:

```js
module.exports = {
  async find( ctx ) {
    let entities;

    if ( ctx.query._q ) {
      entities = await strapi.services.author.search( ctx.query );
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.author.find( ctx.query );
    }

    // Add computed field `fullName` to entities.
    entities.map( entity => {
      entity.fullName = `${entity.firstName} ${entity.lastName}`;

      return entity;
    } );

    return entities.map( entity => sanitizeEntity( entity, { model: strapi.models.author } ) );
  },

  async findOne( ctx ) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    let entity = await strapi.services.author.findOne( { id } );

    if ( ! entity ) {
      return ctx.notFound();
    }

    // Add computed field `fullName` to entity.
    entity.fullName = `${entity.firstName} ${entity.lastName}`;

    return sanitizeEntity( entity, { model: strapi.models.author } );
  },
};
```

This allows REST API calls to get the `fullName` returned and also tells GraphQL to include `fullName` in its schema as well, so `find` and `findOne` can pass it along to GraphQL properly.

I hope this helps because I feel like I just leveled up big time after learning this!

Comment: This is gold! I also feel like I just leveled up after learning this!!!!!!

thanks @wavematt

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me. From the [docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#extending-the-schema), it looks like they've changed `v4` to extend in a global context rather than per module/entity (`src/api/...`). Like so:

```js
// src/index.js

"use strict";

module.exports = {
  register({ strapi }) {
    const extensionService = strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension");

    const extension = () => ({
      typeDefs: `
      type Author {
        fullName: String
      }
      `,
      resolvers: {
        Author: {
          fullName(author) {
            return strapi.service("api::author.author").getFullName(author);
          },
        },
      },
    });

    extensionService.use(extension);
  },
};
```

This could be wrong and I hope it is. It is a step backend in my eyes, architecturally speaking. But, you could always add this logic to a file in each entity folder (such as `src/api/graphql/index.js`), then import it to this global file. A bit like what happening with the service logic above to keep the separation of concerns. It's just a bit 'manual'.

For those that want to see what `strapi.service("api::author.author").getFullName(author)` is calling:

```js
// src/api/author/services/author.js

"use strict";

const { createCoreService } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreService("api::author.author", () => ({
  getFullName(author) {
    return `${author.firstName} ${author.lastName}`;
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Strapi v4 things have changed. See [extending-the-schema](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#extending-the-schema)

For example I extended UploadFile by doing:

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  /**
   * An asynchronous register function that runs before
   * your application is initialized.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to extend code.
   */
  register({ strapi }) {
    const extension = ({ nexus }) => ({
      types: [
        nexus.extendType({
          type: "UploadFile",
          definition: (t) => {
            t.string("path", {
              description: "Path to file on its host.",
              resolve: (root, args, ctx) => (new URL(root.url).pathname),
            });
          },
        }),
      ],
    });

    strapi.plugin("graphql").service("extension").use(extension);
  },

  /**
   * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
   * your application gets started.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
   * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
   */
  bootstrap(/*{ strapi }*/) {},
};
```